# Regular expression for date times

Tags: regex, codeigniter

can anyone tell me what will be the regular expression of the following:

```
yyyy-mm-dd(space)hr:i:s
```

e.g., exactly this format:

```
2001-07-31 22:05:00
```

I have to put this reg expression in ‘regex’

Comment: Do you want to parse a date? Or validate that it is a date? Because most languages support libraries for that, which is better than checking this with a regex (if you want to check for valite dates only, the regex will probably fill your screen as well)

Comment: Actually i want user to input a valid date so if there is any other way to accomplish this as i want this format because i have to put this format's value into database field with type timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the regex library:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```

Comment: @Fredrik I believe that regexps should be used for strings structure validation. The logic should be left for regular code because it's very difficult to properly detect all possible date cases using regexps.

Answer (score 1):

`(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s+(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})`

Parenthesis are if you want to catch the values of year, month etc.

Comment: Yes, this date would make no sense. But it can be incorrect data with correct format, so I think it should also be caught (and validated later). It will be easier to validate it later and throw error e.g. _Incorrect month_

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`[12][0-9]{3}-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]\s[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]`

(with some very basic validation for invalid input like 9999-99-99 99:99:99)

Answer (score 0):

matches a date in yyyy-mm-dd format from between 1900-01-01 and 2099-12-31

```
^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

Comment: This does not capture the time